# Get-WmiObject doesn't work with IP but with FQDN

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-server-2012, powershell-4.0

I have the following PowerShell script.

**Code:**

```
$User = "DOMAIN\user"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "somePassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $PWord 

$query=...

Get-WmiObject -Computer 192.168.172.10 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  -ErrorAction Stop # Fails
Get-WinEvent -FilterXML $query -ComputerName 192.168.172.10 -Credential $Credential -ea stop # Works
```

**Situation:** I'm on a AD server with an IP like 192.168.1.1 and executing my script. [AD has access rights for all subnets and there is no firewall blocking access]

**Issue:** I want to query the following computer: server1 with ip 192.168.172.10 then this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Computer 192.168.172.10 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  -ErrorAction Stop # Fails
```

fails with an "RPC-Server is unavailable" error but this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Computer server1 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  -ErrorAction Stop # Works
```

works and this works too:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterXML $query -ComputerName 192.168.172.10 -Credential $Credential -ea stop # Works
```

The server is in the same domain like the AD and Windows Firewall is for testing purposes disabled.
And a different server "server2" with ip 192.168.172.11 is working both ways with FQDN and ip.

*Does anyone have an idea why in some cases (5 out of hundrets) the Get-WmiObject fails with ip but works with FQDN?*

I searched about similar issues but all are about WinRM and are using commands like Invoke-Command. For sure WinRM first needs to be configured right in that case, but as far as I understood Get-WmIObject does not need WinRM. (I have not done any configuration tasks on all the computers).

Comment: Are you certain that your DNS is returning the names you think it's returning?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Yes, DNS is working fine. Ping returns the right IP and also if I'm using the FQDN with Get-WmiObject -Computer server1 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  -ErrorAction Stop
I'm getting the right server (servername and domain is right). I will check RDNS records.

Comment: I didn't ask if DNS wasn't working. I was asking if it was returning the names you thought it was. Apparently that was not the case, based on your marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue what you are facing is because of the  **reverse DNS records**.

In your case, you might have multiple *RDNS* records for the same *IP*, causing the problem to be intermittent.

Check your reverse lookup zone and the the corresponding *PTR* records.

That should solve your issue.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes you where right: For every failed server there was a wrong PTR record (e.g. 192.168.172.10 -> server3). I deleted them and after they got replicated my script worked fine. Thank you! My question is now why is RDNS needed/important? I'm querying server which have not a RDNS zone or no RDNS PTR. And why Get-WinEvent worked and Get-WmiObject not?. For me this is really confusing.

Comment: @PESP: Reverse lookup zone have certain records including PTR record which inturns resolve the IP Adress to Name. So if you are not mapping that  then it would be confusing for the DNS on which A record it should go if you hit the IP. The A record hold the Name to IPAdress. I hope you got it .ELse you post it . I will answer with screenshots and all. Give me the link too :)

Comment: I think i got it. But what happens if there is no RDNS zone for a subnet? I have some subnets without a RDNS zone and they are working fine. Gets the dns server in that case just "ignored" and no reverse lookup is done?

Comment: So it will work with the hostname then. Nothing will happen id PTR is not there. Only the IPAddress to Name resolution won't work for that. :) Hope it clarifies your doubt mate.

Comment: @PESP: Upvote it also if it helps you , that will help others too. :)

Comment: Upvoted it, but I have less then 15 reputation score and so it's not shown.